# Material won't project on spherical mesh? recreating Earth

Tags: rendering, materials, displacement

I'm recreating the earth using NASA's data, now that I have a displaced mesh ready, it won't show materials in render.
I displaced a smoothed subdivided sphere close to IRL measurement of earth, converted to mesh, UV unwrapped it, imported back into blender.
I did it this way because I had a lot of trouble trying to use a generated projection of a bump/disp map in blender with the displace modifier... and the experimental True displacement in Blender 2.79 stops working after applying a large scale to an object.
For example 12756 km (x & z) by 12713.6 km (y).
My material using generated for vector always worked before,
but below you'll see it won't on this mesh
[image: Displaced Earth Sphere High Poly]
I checked all normals, they're all facing the correct direction.
What could the issue be?

Comment: Can you share the blend file, with external resources packed?

Comment: Plz attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2

Comment: it took a lot of work to make the displaced earth and the maps I'm using. I'd rather not share the exact files. However if you create a sphere with this many faces and physically displace it and then bring it back into blender, it may give the same result of not working. I tried this with another randomly displaced sphere of same subdivision count, same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...
Was ridiculously simple..
Projection needed to be flat not spherical and use UV instead of generated. 
I don't know why the need to switch to flat as it's entirely counter intuitive because every tutorial I've come across says to use spherical for sphere shapes.
I also had an unrelated issue with the UV map in the wrong rotation position.
I fixed that and re-imported and changed project to flat.
Then everything worked! lol weird.
[image: Ultra realistic earth displaced terrain]

Comment: You seem to have also swapped between *Generated* and *UV* texture coordinates. That will make a big difference.

Comment: I'm new to blender, but I don't think that was worth a downvote. I don't see many posts of people trying to make an accurately displaced earth, places online want to charge thousands of dollars to get the high resolution tile downloads of earth in either Geo data type (elevation or satellite images).

Comment: I completely agree, it wasn’t me that down voted. I spotted the difference in texture coordinates and wanted to help. Your results look great - well done. Upvoted :-)